# Parsing xml file from url to a astropy votable without downloading

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, astropy, urlopen

From http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/ you can get the transmission curves for many filters used in astronomical observations. I would like to get these data by opening the url with the corresponding xml file (for each filter), parse it to astropy's votable that helps to read the table data easily.

I have managed to do this by opening the file converting it to a UTF-8 file and saving in locally as an xml. Then opening the local file works fine, as it is obvious form the following example.

However I do not want to save the file and open it again. When I tried that by doing: votable = parse(xml_file), it raises an OSError: File name too long as it takes all the file as a string.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

fltr = 'http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/fps.php?ID=2MASS/2MASS.H'
url = urlopen(fltr).read()
xml_file = url.decode('UTF-8')
with open('tmp.xml','w') as out:
    out.write(xml_file)

votable = parse('tmp.xml')
data = votable.get_first_table().to_table(use_names_over_ids=True)

print(votable)
print(data["Wavelength"])
```

The output in this case is:

```
<VOTABLE>... 1 tables ...</VOTABLE>
Wavelength
AA    
----------
12890.0
13150.0
...
18930.0
19140.0
Length = 58 rows
```

Comment: You can use stringio to wrap the data, but see also https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/pull/1498

Comment: I think "without downloading" is a little deceptive--you are still downloading the file, but just processing it in memory without writing it out to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed [according to the API documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.io.votable.parse.html#astropy.io.votable.parse), `votable.parse`'s first argument is either a filename or a readable file-like object.  It doesn't specify this exactly, but apparently the file also has to be *seekable* meaning that it can be read with random access.

The `HTTPResponse` object returned by `urlopen` is indeed a file-like object with a `.read()` method, so in principle it might be possible to pass directly to `parse()`, but this is how I found out it has to be seekable:

```
fltr = 'http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/fps.php?ID=2MASS/2MASS.H'
u = urlopen(fltr)
>>> parse(u)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "astropy/io/votable/table.py", line 135, in parse
    _debug_python_based_parser=_debug_python_based_parser) as iterator:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "astropy/utils/xml/iterparser.py", line 157, in get_xml_iterator
    with _convert_to_fd_or_read_function(source) as fd:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "astropy/utils/xml/iterparser.py", line 63, in _convert_to_fd_or_read_function
    with data.get_readable_fileobj(fd, encoding='binary') as new_fd:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "astropy/utils/data.py", line 210, in get_readable_fileobj
    fileobj.seek(0)
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

So you need to wrap the data in a seekable file-like object.  Along the lines that @keflavich wrote you can use `io.BytesIO` (`io.StringIO` won't work as explained below).

It turns out that there's no reason to explicitly decode the UTF-8 data to unicode.   I'll spare the example, but after trying it myself it turns out `parse()` works on raw bytes (which I find a bit odd, but okay).  So you can read the entire contents of the URL into an `io.BytesIO` which is just an in-memory file-like object that supports random access:

```
>>> u = urlopen(fltr)
>>> s = io.BytesIO(u.read())
>>> v = parse(s)
WARNING: W42: None:2:0: W42: No XML namespace specified [astropy.io.votable.tree]
>>> v.get_first_table().to_table(use_names_over_ids=True)
<Table masked=True length=58>
Wavelength Transmission
    AA
 float32     float32
---------- ------------
   12890.0          0.0
   13150.0          0.0
       ...          ...
   18930.0          0.0
   19140.0          0.0
```

This is, in general, the way in Python to do something with some data as though it were a file, without writing an actual file to the filesystem.

Note, however, this won't work if the entire file can't fit in memory.  In that case you still might need to write it out to disk.  But if it's just for some temporary processing and you don't want to litter your disk `tmp.xml` like in your example, you can always use the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) module to, among other things, create temporary files that are automatically deleted once they're no longer in use.

Comment: Yes, that indeed worked. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I am slightly surprised that `votable.parse` implicitly requires a seekable file object. It could be more clever and handle this case transparently, though as you can see the workaround is straightforward enough.